# Reliable measure of orientation change in a 3D shape

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, 3d

I have been measuring the change in orientation of a 3D shape (a 3-space sensor) with different starting positions for a controlled end position.

I am using Euler angles, (P)itch, (R)oll and (Y)aw. 
My measure of orientation change Is: 
Orientation change OC = |dP| + |dR| + |dY|

The 3 starting positions differ only in sensor roll in degrees:

1). 0

2). 45

3). 90

With each starting position the sensor is tared then elevated to 30 degrees along the roll axis.

The problem is that for 1). & 3). as expected I get OC = 30, representing only pitch and only yaw error of 30 degrees respectively. However for 2). OC is significantly >30 being a sum of non-zero pitch, roll and yaw.

Is this as expected? Assuming it is, is there a better measure of OC which is not sensitive to starting position?

Answer (score 1):

See here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59013791/4833760

The answer was to use a quaternion distance, this was the dot product of the initial and final quaternions which my sensor supplied as unit quaternions where x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup> + z<sup>2</sup> + w<sup>2</sup> = 1

The dot product was given by:
dot = x<sub>i</sub>.x<sub>f</sub> + y<sub>i</sub>.y<sub>f</sub> + z<sub>i</sub>.z<sub>f</sub> + w<sub>i</sub>.w<sub>f</sub>

Furthermore I used the relative angle theta (radians) between these quaternions given by:
Theta = 2cos<sup>-1</sup>(dot)

The sensors gave greatly improved results using theta, which only improved more when they had a gradient descent calibration applied.